# Update array in array of object using previous state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following state in my app:

```js
  const [education, setEducation] = useState([
    {
      institution: "University",
      area: "President",
      studyType: "Bachelor",
      startDate: "2013-01-01",
      endDate: "2014-01-01",
      gpa: "4.0",
      courses: ["DB1101 - Basic SQL"],
    },
  ]);
```

And the following method to update the state:

```js
  const onCoursesChange = (newValue, index) => {
    const newValuesArr = newValue ? newValue.map(item => item.value) : [];
    setEducation((prev)=>(
      prev[index].courses=newValuesArr
    ));
   //setEducation(education[index].courses = newValuesArr);
    console.log(education[index].courses)    
  };
```

With the above code I get the error `Cannot create property 'courses' on string 'asdfa'` when the array `newValuesArr`  has more than one element.

How do I update the state ??

Comment: Can you share your whole component as well as the console.log of `newValue`? Also in which part of the state do you want to update?

Comment: You can find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-jgdk7?file=/example.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
setEducation((prev)=>(
  prev[index].courses=newValuesArr
));
```

`prev[index].courses=newValuesArr` is an assignment that simply returns the value being assigned, here `newValuesArr`. This is an array of strings, so its elements do not have the properties you expect.

Your state-updating function (the one passed to `setEducation`) instead needs a return the whole of `prev`, with the update you desire. And this should be done immutably - that is, without updating `prev`. Luckily, ES6 offers nice tools for doing this. Here is how you can do it in this case:

```
setEducation((prev)=>(
  prev.map((item, oldIndex) => oldIndex === index ? { ...item, courses: newValuesarr } : item )
));
```

That is, it `maps` through the array `prev`, and leaves all unchanged apart from the one with the matching `index`, and in that one updates the `courses` property to the desired array.

Comment: Thanks man very insightful answer. Where can I find resource about updating state immutably coz I'm having hard time understanding it ?